# entr and go run not playing nice

Tags: go, webserver, restart

I'm doing some light web development in [`go`](http://golang.org/), and running into a problem with [`entr`](http://entrproject.org/). I'm editing `.go` files in a directory while having

```
ls *.go | entr -r go run *.go
```

running in a separate terminal window.

I can see it re-starting my program every time I save a file, because some format statements get printed out to the terminal every time I do so. However, whenever I navigate to `localhost:8080`, I see the handler content that was present when I started `entr` (rather than the content in the most recent change). If I `Ctrl+C`, then restart `entr`, I see the latest changes.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the minimal example:

```
// test.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handler (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello there! I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting up...")
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Now, if I run `ls test.go | entr -r go run test.go`, I see `Starting up...` printed to the terminal, and I can go to `localhost:8080/tests` to see a page that says `"Hello there! I love tests!"`. If I change the `handler` function so that it reads

```
func handler (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "I guess %s are ok...", r.URL.Path[1:])
}
```

I see the `Starting up...` message printed in terminal again, but going to `localhost:8080/tests` still gives me the page showing `"Hello there! I love tests!"` (even in incognito mode). If I then kill the `entr` process and restart it, I can go to `localhost:8080/tests` to see `I guess tests are ok...` as expected.

**Edit**:

Getting the error out of `ListenAndServe` confirms that this has to do with a dangling socket.

```
...
   err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
   fmt.Printf("ListenAndServe ERR: %s\n", err)
...
```

shows the extra line

```
listen tcp :8080: bind: address already in use
```

in terminal. A quick search tells me that there isn't an easy way to stop a listener started with `ListenAndServe`. Is there a simpler approach than [this](http://www.hydrogen18.com/blog/stop-listening-http-server-go.html)?

Comment: If you would handle the errors ListenAndServe returns you would see what is wrong (and we could help). Probably your port is still in use and there is not much you can do about it except properly shutting down your app.

Comment: As a side note, something like `go list -f '{{join .GoFiles " "}}'` is probably safer than using `*.go` to either `ls` or `go run` (e.g. that will skip `*_test.go` files and honor [build constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints)). You should probably also be using `go build` instead of `go run` (or `go build && ./yourProgName`).

Answer (score 2):

The ls command only lists the go files in your current directory. The command should be like this to listen to go files in all subfolders in the project.

```
find . | grep '\.go' | entr -r go run .
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem:
`go run` will start the server in a separate process which won't be killed.

A solution:
Use a little script which kills and starts the server

```
#!/bin/sh
pkill "$1"
go run "$1.go"
```

and use this for `entr`.

Answer (score 1):

In linux there are two process created. First is the go run main.go and the second is the /tmp/go-build/b001/exe/main. The second one needs to be killed to terminate the program not the first...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34246337)